# How to set datetime variable in SQL Server 2008

Tags: sql-server-2008

```
declare @test as DATETIME

set @test='21/03/2014'

print @test

select @test

set @test=21/03/2014

print @test

select @test

set @test=21-03-2014

print @test

select @test

set @test=03/21/2014

print @test

select @test

set @test=2014/21/03

print @test

select @test

set @test=2014/03/21

print @test

select @test
```

this code gives wrong output so plz tell me code to assign datetime variable in SQLServer 2008

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
declare @test datetime

set @test='03/21/2014'

//set @test='21/03/2014' This is not valid you must give date in MM/dd/yyyy

print @test



set @test='2014/03/21'

print @test
```